# Path for Command Line Prompt Across Windows OS

Tags: windows, command-line, path

this question might seem counter-useful.

the path for the windows command line prompt is different across several windows OSes.  i'd like to know if there is a command i can enter in the command line prompt that will output the path of the command line prompt.

Comment: No, it's actually a very good question!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `COMSPEC` environment variable contains this information. It seems to be available consistently since the olden days of MS-DOS. ([Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ComSpec))

```
echo %COMSPEC%

C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe
```

Note that it can be altered freely using `SET COMSPEC=`, so it's not 1000% reliable.

Answer (score 1):

I use a script called `which.bat` which prints out the full path to a specified executable (equivalent to Unix `which` or `whereis`):

```
@for %%e in (%PATHEXT%) do @for %%i in (%1%%e) do @if NOT "%%~$PATH:i"=="" echo %%~$PATH:i
```

So, to find out the path to the `cmd` program you would invoke the following:

```
> which.bat cmd
C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe
```